# How to get metadata from a file in c

Tags: c, linux, file, metadata

I need to create a program in c and then build some code in the way that allows me to see what the metadata is in a file, not creating a header, just from any file. I've been searching this all around but still didn't find anything. I need to create a program in c able to read file system information about that file, size, type of file (normal, diredctory, link, etc.), i-node, owner, creation time and last modification. I know how to open the file and such, but I have no idea how to read that metadata. I appreciate de help. Also it's in linux

Comment: Sounds like few chapters in some Linux programming book.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create file header (metadata of file) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629283/create-file-header-metadata-of-file-in-c)

Comment: Use [`lstat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html) or [`stat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) if you have the path to the file; and [`fstat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) if you have the descriptor. If you have an open file handle `FILE *handle;`, use `fstat(fileno(handle), &info)` (with `struct stat info;`).

Comment: I'll only use the system calls like the _open_ to open files, but will try that `lstat()` and `stat()`. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewHenle no, it's different. I don't have to create a metadata header

Comment: Sometimes, a LMGTFY link is actually appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try fstat()?

Man page link: https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat